# Create frequency Tables for all the categorical variables of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame that has columns containing both continuous and categorical variables. I want to create frequency table for all the categorical variables using pandas.

I have used `.value_counts()` function to generate the table, but it is giving me a list.

## This code returns a list

```
for i in Customer_Final.columns:
      if Customer_Final[i].dtype=='object':
            print(Customer_Final[i].value_counts())
```

## The output is

```
13-07-2011    35
25-09-2011    33
22-11-2011    33
21-12-2013    33
23-10-2011    33
9/3/2013      32
25-08-2012    32
25-11-2012    32
4/1/2013      31
1/1/2014      31
7/10/2011     31
11/10/2012    31
3/2/2014      31
6/10/2012     31
17-04-2011    31
15-03-2013    31
5/4/2012      31
7/5/2012      31
11/5/2012     31
29-02-2012    30
18-02-2012    30
23-05-2012    30
13-06-2011    30
15-09-2013    30
18-12-2013    30
6/8/2013      29
3/1/2014      29
26-09-2011    29
23-07-2012    29
26-07-2011    29
              ..
7/2/2012      12
29-08-2011    12
16-05-2013    12
6/1/2014      12
26-11-2012    12
10/9/2013     12
24-11-2013    12
21-05-2011    12
11/4/2013     12
23-04-2013    12
25-12-2011    12
4/6/2011      11
13-04-2013    11
23-05-2011    11
26-05-2013    11
27-11-2013    11
15-05-2012    11
24-01-2012    11
6/4/2011      10
27-01-2012    10
21-05-2013    10
15-04-2012     9
9/12/2012      8
29-01-2012     6
22-02-2014     3
23-02-2014     2
24-02-2014     2
27-02-2014     1
28-02-2014     1
21-02-2014     1
Name: tran_date, Length: 1129, dtype: int64
e-Shop            9311
MBR               4661
Flagship store    4577
TeleShop          4504
Name: Store_type, dtype: int64
27-12-1988    32
17-09-1982    32
25-02-1974    27
20-03-1972    25
18-11-1991    24
09-06-1970    24
26-05-1977    23
20-12-1981    22
08-03-1983    22
21-07-1988    22
08-05-1988    21
08-09-1987    21
05-12-1992    21
16-04-1978    21
23-06-1986    21
06-12-1982    21
19-03-1971    20
20-04-1980    20
10-11-1973    20
21-03-1990    20
27-11-1991    19
11-07-1971    19
29-06-1985    19
02-02-1974    19
26-09-1988    19
26-06-1975    19
14-06-1989    19
08-10-1987    19
07-05-1974    19
17-08-1976    19
              ..
29-01-1972     1
03-10-1972     1
03-03-1980     1
22-01-1986     1
01-11-1977     1
01-05-1980     1
01-09-1992     1
04-01-1991     1
08-05-1981     1
06-06-1980     1
14-07-1979     1
28-08-1988     1
02-01-1985     1
29-01-1979     1
19-08-1980     1
08-05-1979     1
21-07-1980     1
12-09-1970     1
23-08-1991     1
04-05-1981     1
29-07-1985     1
22-01-1989     1
23-04-1992     1
01-06-1972     1
21-07-1986     1
10-08-1984     1
12-07-1977     1
14-04-1984     1
26-08-1987     1
01-05-1982     1
Name: DOB, Length: 3987, dtype: int64
M    11811
F    11233
Name: Gender, dtype: int64
Books               6069
Electronics         4898
Home and kitchen    4129
Footwear            2999
Clothing            2960
Bags                1998
Name: prod_cat, dtype: int64
Women                  3048
Mens                   2912
Kids                   1997
Tools                  1062
Fiction                1043
Kitchen                1037
Children               1035
Comics                 1031
Mobiles                1031
Bath                   1023
Furnishing             1007
Non-Fiction            1004
DIY                     989
Cameras                 985
Personal Appliances     972
Academic                967
Computers               958
Audio and video         952
Name: prod_subcat, dtype: int64
```

I want to see separate data-frames of the frequency table for each column which has categorical variables in it. But, How can I do this using Pandas?

## So, I thought Groupby should help, and written this code

```
for i in Customer_Final.columns:
    if Customer_Final[i].dtype=='object':
      return Customer_Final.groupby([i]).count.reset_index()
```

## But got error

```
File "<ipython-input-16-5889a174ef03>", line 3
return Customer_Final.groupby([i]).count().reset_index()
^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Please help on How I can return Dataframes containing frequency tables of all the categorical variables?
Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Your first block of code prints pandas Series objects, not lists. To convert a Series to a DataFrame you can just wrap it in `pd.DataFrame()`. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html.

Comment: Also, your second block of code is wrong - as the error message says you cannot use "return" outside a function. In your case you should probably use print instead.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Can you make an example of an DataFrame you would like to have?

Comment: Dataframes containing count of distinct elements within each column. Let's say I have gender column. It should return count of M and F. So M-1150.    F-1300 with headers as gender and count

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
# Frequency tables for each categorical feature
for column in data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
    display(pd.crosstab(index=data[column], columns='% observations', normalize='columns')*100)
```